# jQuery change height of container on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, click

I have a container with numerous photos in, I want to restrict the height of my container to 440px with a "show more" link below it. When the user clicks show more I want the height of my container to move to 880px and then 1320px.

My code currently reads like this

```
$('#photo_container').css('max-height','440px');
$('#photo_container').css('overflow','hidden');
$('.show_more').click(function(){
    $('#photo_container').css('max-height','880px');
});
```

And html is:

```
<div id="photo_container">
    ....PHOTOS IN HERE
</div>
<div class="show_more">Show More</div>
```

Comment: The div is called 'photocontainer' but in your code you have 'photo_container'.  Also, you have 'funtion' instead of 'function'. Lastly, max-height is mostly unsupported.

Comment: Ah yes, stupid typos - the function one sorted that! good eyes!

Comment: @JacobM "moslty unsupported" is a rather large overstatement. You have to go back to IE 6 and earlier to not have `max-height` supported. Here's a great site to track browser support of features: http://caniuse.com/#search=max-height

Comment: Ah, fair point.  My misreading of a chart on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height

Answer (score 1):

Change `max-height` to `height`:

```
$('#photo_container').css('height','440px');
$('#photo_container').css('overflow','hidden');
$('.show_more').click(function(){
    $('#photo_container').css('height','880px');
});
```